# Drupal 8 Stylesheet Changes Have to Rebuild Cache Everytime. Is There a Better Way?

Tags: stylesheet, drupal-8, drush

I'm converting a static website into a Drupal 8 template and everytime I change something in the stylesheet I have to do 'drush cr'. Is there a better way to do this? I've disabled CSS and JS aggregation and I've followed everything listed on this link https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable cache
[Clearing cache in Drupal 8](https://www.chapterthree.com/blog/how-to-turn-off-drupal-8-caching)